# Photo Competition 2021-03-15: Reflections

Tags: photo-competition

#### Theme

The theme of this contest is simple: photos where mirrors, windows, water, or other reflective surfaces were used to get reflections.

This theme was suggested by [Eric S](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/60648/eric-s).

#### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on March 15, 2021 at 12:00 AM UTC**. The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.**
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

Good luck!

Comment: **AM**: photos taken in the late/early hours of the day from 00:00 to 04:00

Comment: Theme: Red. Photos where the subject / majority of image is naturally red or red tinted.

Comment: The previous competition is locked, so I'll comment here. Thank you very much for the bounty, and congrats for your win!

Comment: Domestic Animals: Cats, dogs, pets. Not wild or exotic.

Comment: Theme: Transportation, like trains, cars, ships, bicycle, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]Subject: Local Lake

Location: Vancouver Island, Canada

Date: January 2021

[Long Exposure Over Local Lake](https://www.instagram.com/p/CK_mD9HMYje/)

Comment: Beautiful photo! What was your exposure, if you recall?

Comment: 25 second exposures shot in interval shooting and stitched together in post.  Total shooting time around 1 hour.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

date :27/02/2020. 
Place Piha Beach NZ. 
Title: How I need to feel!

Answer (score 9):

Location: So-called Fontänenteich (fountain pond) at [Bergpark Wilhelmshöhe, Kassel, Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bergpark_Wilhelmsh%C3%B6he) ([exact Location](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=51.3147&mlon=9.4124#map=15/51.3147/9.4124))

Date: 11/10/2020

Subject: Reflections of an autumn forest in a pond

Camera: Samsung S9 (no editing)

[image]

Comment: Cant believe to see that here. I almost visit Kassel every year and I love to spend time in this park. Its one of my favorite places. Great image.

Answer (score 9):

Beijing Art District, D-Park reflection, June 2012

[image: Beijing art district]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Subject: Loch Stack with Arkle (Corbett hill)

Location: Loch Stack, Scotland

Date: 2019-05-15

Answer (score 9):

Title: "House of Mirrors"[image]
Location: Rome, Italy.
Subject: Shaving Essentials shop.
Date: September, 2017.

Comment: I feel this photo captured the spirit of the theme more than any other. Great job!

Answer (score 8):

San Antonio, TX, USA - Japanese Tea Garden - 2021/01/03

Canon EOS 5D Mark IV w/ EF 24-105mm f/4L @ 105mm, 1/200, f/5.6, ISO 100

[image: San Antonio Japanese Tea Garden]

Answer (score 6):

The Netherlands, Mirror for sale, September 2017

[image: Mirror for sale with dimensions]

Comment: Did you use a shift lens for this?

Comment: No, just plain old photoshop. How would I keep the camera out of the mirror with a shift lens?

Comment: by setting the camera just to the side of the mirror, aimed perpendicular to the (extended) plane of the mirror, and applying lateral shift towards the mirror. See: ["The Vampire Effect"](https://www.popphoto.com/how-to/2011/05/complete-guide-to-tiltshift-photography/?page=0,3) section of this link.

Answer (score 6):

**Heron, reflection.**

An infrequent visitor to my local park in North London. First time he was ever close enough to be under 300mm & I didn't have to crop the snot out of it afterwards ;)
D5500 240mm f/6.3 1/2000s ISO 1000
[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Amidala's Palace on the planet Naboo**

[image: Naboo]

Plaza de España in Sevilla, Spain (*Where they shot Naboo Palace for Star Wars)*

November 6th, 2018

Answer (score 4):

Location: Yosemite

Date: 8/10/2020

Subject: Reflection Rocks

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Under the mountains by Peter Badida on 500px.com]

- Title: [Under the mountains](https://500px.com/photo/1024707049)
- Location: [Štrbské pleso, High Tatras, Slovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0trbsk%C3%A9_pleso)
- Subject: Mountains & lake
- Date: 15.11.2020

You can find me at [500px.com](https://500px.com/peterbadida).

Answer (score 4):

Title: True colors

Location: Along the Tonawanda Creek bike trail

Date: September 28, 2020

Camera: Pixel 4A

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmhWu.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 4):

Subject: Corridor Bridge

Location: Guizhou, China

Date: 11/18/2013

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Shot September 2007,

Outtake from a shoot of some guitar amplifier tubes for an album cover, *[60 Watt Avenue](https://www.discogs.com/The-Whipsaws-60-Watt-Avenue/master/1893627)*,  for a local band, The Whipsaws.

Answer (score 3):

Location: San Francisco

Date: 6/27/2020

Subject: A Light's Perspective

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: New Year 2019 in Moscow]

**New Year 2019 in Moscow**, January 03 2019. *Huawei P20 Pro*

Answer (score 3):

Evening at the Lake Inari, Finland, 9/9/2018
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Location: Nagoya, Japan

Date: 14th April 2019

Subject: Rainy Intersection

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Date: October 13, 2015
- Location: Burgundy, France
- Camera: Olympus E-M1
- Taken during a barge trip.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

- Title: Reflection in my Puppy's Eye
- Location: Lincolnshire, UK
- Date: January 2021

Answer (score 1):

Location: Yosemite

Date: 8/11/2020

Subject: Internal Reflections

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Reflections of a hammerhead flash**

Before a wardrobe mirror, Reflections of a Hammerhead Flash, 2020-Nov-09
[image: Reflections of a hammerhead flash]

I have no idea where half of those reflections are from and why they are partially colored: there was just a single mirror involved in front of the camera.  All other reflection surfaces have to be lens and teleconverter (or other camera parts) in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Location: Waters of Leith Walk, Edinburgh Scotland
Date: 7th September 2015
Title: The Waters of Leith

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Subject: Salzach

Location: Werfen, Austria

Date: August 2019

Answer (score 0):

[image: Remarkables]

- Title: The dying of the light
- Subject: Remarkable Range and Lake Wakatipu, Queenstown, New Zealand
- Date: 10 July 2020
- Camera: Samsung S8 phone, no processing.